# Newly built MySQL Galera Cluster does not start up in CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, galera, mysql-cluster, centos-7

I am setting up a 3 node MySQL Galera Cluster lab environment. All 3 nodes are CentOS 7 and followed the steps in below blog to setup mysql-wsrep-5.7

> https://www.dreamvps.com/tutorials/install-mysql-galera-cluster-centos-7/

After setting up I am starting the first node by executing:

```
>/usr/bin/mysqld_bootstrap
```

But MySQL service fails to start with below error in log:

> ```
> 2019-02-04T13:13:10.053481Z 0 [ERROR] WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 110: failed to reach primary view: 110 (Connection timed out) at gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():158 
> 2019-02-04T13:13:10.053494Z 0 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():209: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
> 2019-02-04T13:13:10.053635Z 0 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1458: Failed to open channel 'galera_cluster' at 'gcomm://192.168.50.50:3306,192.168.50.51:3306,192.168.50.52:3306': -110 (Connection timed out) 
> 2019-02-04T13:13:10.053647Z 0 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out 
> 2019-02-04T13:13:10.053652Z 0 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://192.168.50.50:3306,192.168.50.51:3306,192.168.5.52:3306) failed: 7 
> 2019-02-04T13:13:10.053661Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
> ```

Form the log it is clear that it is not starting up as the first node in the cluster as it should do, rather it is trying to establish connection to other nodes.

I also checked `/var/lib/m.ysql/grastate.dat`, `safe_to_bootstrap` is already set to 1. But still I don't know why I get this behaviour?

How should I start up the first node in my MySQL Galera Cluster?

Comment: A few things to check: Is SELinux running in enforcing mode? Run `sestatus` to find out. If so, you'll have to put it into permissive mode or disable it. Also, are the necessary ports open in the firewall? Maybe just try with the firewall disabled to start with, just to be sure that's not blocking you.

Comment: Hi.. I stopped firewalld and disabled SElinux and still same error . I could see one strange warning in the log                                                                            `[Warning] WSREP: access file(/var/lib/mysql//gvwstate.dat) failed(No such file or directory)` . My only question is why the /usr/bin/mysqld_bootstrap script is not starting the node as first node in cluster.  Instead of checking  `/var/lib/mysql/grastate.dat` which has safe_to_bootstrap value, why it is checking `/var/lib/mysql//gvwstate.dat` invalid location.

Comment: You could try to edit the config file and set `wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://` - that used to be the way to bootstrap before scripts such as `mysqld_bootstrap`. Other tutorials also mention scripts / commands such as: `galera_new_cluster` and `mysqld_safe --wsrep-new-cluster` which also could be worth a try. I wouldn't worry about the warning about not finding gvwstate.dat - this is expected, I think.

Comment: Warning [galera system looking error message may be a lie](https://github.com/codership/galera/pull/109).